# C# Application - Cannot connect to on-line database

Tags: c#, mysql, connection, hosting

My team has developed a desktop application (in c#) and web application for a project, however we are having trouble connecting the desktop application to the web hosted mysql database. The web application can connect fine and perform all the required actions.

We plan to push the application out to multiple machines, what would be the best way to guarantee a connection from the desktop application to the database?

Can anyone also recommend a good host that allows this function? as this may be the problem.

Apologise for the vague question, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add more details?  Are you trying to connect directly from the installed desktop app to the DB server, or are you going through a web service of some sort?

Comment: what's the difference in the connection strings in the web app vs the desktop application.. I am assuming that you are using the app.config's `<connectionStrings>` nodes to add keys for your connectionstring can you show code of where the connection is failing as well as the config settings for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done many applications which connects MySql server hosted in GoDaddy. I'll give a sample how i do that

```
MySqlConnection conn;
MySqlCommand comm;
MySqlDataReader read;
string
server = "50.60.170.180",
database = "this_is_my_database_name",
dbPassword = "this_is_my_password",
dbUserName = "this_is_my_user_name";

string ConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        return "SERVER=" + server + ";DATABASE=" + database + ";UID=" + dbUserName + ";PASSWORD=" + dbPassword;
    }
}

void InitDB()
{
     conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
     conn.Open();
     comm = new MySqlCommand();
     comm.Connection = conn;
}

void ReadEntry() 
{
     comm.CommandText = "Select * From MyTable";
     read = comm.ExecuteReader();
     while (read.Read()) 
     {
         string i_got_something_from_the_web = read[0].ToString();
     }
     read.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to connect to your database directly if you are hosting it at a 3rd party host.

The best way to connect to your database is via a restful service that is secured by means of secret keys/passwords and https. This service can be part of your website.

Regarding the host, it all depends where the desktop app will be used. You need to make sure that the latency between your desktop app and the host is not to slow. You will also need to look at your budget and see what you can afford.